# Wanted: terms and info for "display density" / "space conciousness" by Gmail

Tags: layout, space-constraints

In gmail, the contents of the page is beautifully laid out with regards to how big the browser window is. There are three modes: *Comfortable*, *Cozy*, and *Compact*. There is a menu for switching manually, but otherwise it switches for you, intelligently.

[image: Display Density]

My question is: **What are the accepted terms for this behavior?** I call it "Space conciousness". In the menu in Gmail they call it "Display Density".

I am implementing this behaviour in some products of our own. But with the terms as general as above, I have a hard time finding discussions about it on forums like these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When [Google blogged](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/changing-information-density-in-gmails.html)  about the changes with respect to responsive design and the display density the title of the article was **Changing information density in Gmail’s new look**

**Information density** seems about the best description to me.

Here's a section from the article above

> We also thought quite a bit about the density of the information on
>   the screen in the new design. Gmail’s old design packs a huge amount
>   of information into a small space. While this is perfect for some,
>   many people appreciate a more airy design with more whitespace between
>   lines and elements on the page. This is especially true on larger
>   monitors.
>
> We wanted Gmail to be more attractive and easier to read by default,
>   so if you’re on a larger monitor you will see that the items in your
>   inbox are spaced farther apart than they were in the old design. We
>   believe that this results in a better overall experience, but it does
>   take some getting used to. In our internal testing we found that most
>   of us adjusted to the new spacing after about a week and found the old
>   spacing cramped and uncomfortable when they looked back at the old
>   design.
>
> Others, however, found the original spacing to be ideal and wanted to
>   see as much information as possible without scrolling, even on a large
>   monitor. We added a density setting to the gear menu in the toolbar to
>   make sure that everybody can find a setting that works for them:
>   Comfortable, Cozy, or Compact.

Comment: That would make the behaviour of changing it with regards to available area to be called "Changing information density".

Comment: "Adaptive spacing" or "adaptive density" perhaps.